# Characterization of finite fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a finite field of order $q$ and with $p = char(\mathbb{K})$. Let $\mathbb{K} = \{\lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_q\}$.
I know that

$x^q - x = \prod_{i=1}^{q}{(x-\lambda_i)}$

So if I expand the RHS I get

$$x^q - x = \sum_{k=0}^{q}{(-1)^{q-k} x^k e_{q-k}(\lambda_0 , \dots , \lambda_q)}$$

Where $e_k$ is the $k$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $q$-variables

Since the equation holds componentwise I get

$$ e_{k}(\lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_q) = \sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_k }{ \lambda_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot \lambda_{i_k} } = (-1)^{k+1} \delta^{k}_{q-1}$$

Where $\delta^{i}_j$ denotes the Kronecker delta symbol.

I consider now the ring $R$ of the polynomial in $q$-variables over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, so
$$R := \mathbb{Z}[x_1 , \dots , x_q]$$

I consider the homomorphism map $\pi \, : \, R \to \mathbb{K}$ such that $\pi(x_i) = \lambda_i$ (and $\pi(1) = 1$ )

Clearly $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x_1 , \dots , x_q]}{ker(\pi)} \cong \mathbb{K}$

From the previous discussion, I know that

$e_k(x_1, \dots , x_q) + (-1)^k \delta^k_{q-1} \in ker(\pi)$

Also, since $p =char(\mathbb{K})$, I know that
$p \in ker(\pi)$

My question is, if I let $I$ be the ideal generated by $p$ and the elements $e_k(x_1 , \dots , x_q) + (-1)^k \delta^k_{q-1}$, is it true that $I = ker(\pi)$ ?

Comment: @KCd I've edited the question as you asked me to do.

Comment: Suppose that $\lambda_1=1$ in $\mathbb{K}$. Consider the polynomial $x_1-1\in\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_q]$, it belongs to $\ker(\pi)$.

Moreover, one can see that $I$ is generated by symmetric polynomials, hence if $(x_1-1)\in I$, then one would also find in $\ker(\pi)$ all the polynomials $x_i-1$.

Therefore $I\subsetneq\ker(\pi)$.

Comment: Indeed, any permutation of the $x_n$ gives an automorphism of $S=\Bbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$. If $S$ was an integral domain then comparing $X^q-X$ with $\prod_{n=1}^q (X-x_n)$, some $x_i=0$ and $x_j=1$, but there is no automorphism of an integral domain sending $0$ to $1$.